# Changing 'updated_at' field name in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema who has the following timestamp properties:

```
timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'updatedAt' }
```

Meaning that the documents in the collection have the fields 'updated_at' and 'created_at'.
If I want to rename both of those fields back to 'createdAt' and 'updatedAt' in a $rename operation:

```
$rename: {
    created_at: 'createdAt',
    updated_at: 'updatedAt'
 }
```

...The 'updated_at' field remains (obviously, as I didn't change the timestamps line in the schema.
But If I already change the timestamps schema to the line:

```
timestamps: true
```

Who supposed to set the updated_at field to updateAt, I get an 'empty $rename object' error, as mongoose doesn't recognize the 'updated_at' field anymore.

How can I complete this field name transformation successfully then?

** Bonus question: In a collection with a large amount of documents, this operation takes HOURS to perform. Is there a way to increase the speed of this operation?

Comment: Show the actual update statement you are trying to issue and turn on `mongoose.set('debug', true)`. At a guess, you probably have to set `timestamps: false` when issuing the update, or simply do `Model.collection.update()` in order to "bypass" what update operators mongoose is trying to add.

Comment: Schema.updateMany({}, {
        $rename: {
         created_at: 'createdAt',
            updated_at: 'updatedAt'
        }
    });

Comment: Yes. I would say definitely doe `Schema.collection.updateMany({}, { "$rename": { created_at: 'createdAt', updated_at: 'updatedAt' } })`. And frankly if you even need to run that in mongoose at all, since you could simply use something like the shell to issue it. Unfortunately the `{ "multi": true }` option ( which is already set by the `updateMulti()` method is as fast as it gets. But in short, bypass the "schema" with the `.collection` accessor to go directly to the driver. This stops mongoose attempting to "rewrite" the update statement.

Comment: Thanks for the collection tip! But the operation is still pretty slow... Does indexing may be helpful? is there a way to monitor the progress of documents updated in the operation?

Comment: Actually "dropping" indexes would speed things up if they were on these fields. Otherwise no. There's no query and therefore no index selection. But if the operation is causing additional writes to indexes on those fields it would be far more efficient to drop them and then create the indexes again after the operation was finished.